# JAXB, how to skip class tag when included

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I'm trying to get that XML:

```
<person>
    <foo>thing</foo>
    <bar>other</bar>
</person>
```

from that code

```
public class Person {
    private InnerThing in;
}

public class InnerThing {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}
```

with JAXB java annotations.

By default, I get

```
<person>
    <innerThing>
        <foo>thing</foo>
        <bar>other</bar>
    </innerThing>
</person>
```

How can I skip the InnerThing tag with just annotations?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but I've not delved deeply into JAXB so I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s @XmlPath annotation to solve this problem (I'm the MOXy tech lead):

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlPath(".")
    private InnerThing in;

}
```

**For More Information:**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html